# EmguCV C# : FindContours() to detect different shapes

Tags: c#, emgucv, detection, contour

I have this image :

[image]

What I try to do is detecting the contours of it. So with looking to the documentation and some code on the web I made this :

```
Image<Gray, byte> image = receivedImage.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(80), new Gray(255));
        Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        Mat hier = new Mat();

        CvInvoke.FindContours(image, contours, hier, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

        CvInvoke.DrawContours(receivedImage, contours, 0, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
```

Then it detects this contour in blue :

[image]

Now I would like to detect both rectangles in differents contours. So the result would be this :

[image]

(made with paint) So now I would like to detect the two rectangles separetely, (the blue and red rectangles would be two different contours). But I have no idea about how to do that !

Thanks in advance for your help ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the process of `ThresholdBinary`. As I assume you understand, this method will return a binary image, whereby all pixels above or equal to the `threshold` parameter, will be pulled up to `maxValue` parameter, and all those below, pulled down to 0. The produced image will consist therefore of only two values (binary), `0` or `maxValue`. If we follow your example with some **assumed** gray values:

[image: Input Image]

After `Image<Gray, byte> image = receivedImage.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(80), new Gray(255));`, you will produce:

[image: Binary Image]

This is in fact the image that you are passing to `CvInvoke.FindContours()` and subsequently finding only the out most contour.

What you need, if indeed you want to continue with `FindContours`, is an  algorithm that will "bin", or "bandpass" your image to first produce the following segments, each to be converted to binary, and contour detected independently.

[image: Segment 1] [image: Segment 2]

I feel that you currently example is probably and over simplification of the problem to offer you a solution on how you might achieve that here. However please do ask another question with more realistic data, and I will be happy to provide some suggestions.

**Alternatively** look towards more sophisticated edge detection methods such and Canny or Sobel. This video may be a good starting point: [Edge Detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifwppzoD-h4)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's' your upvote @Johnny but did this answer your question?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot, your first answer about the External/List mode made think and take a look about the threshold where I found the mistake you explained and my solution with playing with Threshold and alternatives. And now I understood it a lot better thanks to your explanation, and how my solution actually works ^^
Really thanks a lot, you rock !

Comment: @Johnny, Ha, you're very welcome, it was a well asked question and I love EmguCV! I keep an eye on the tag so if you ask another I'll most likely see it. Kindly mark the answer as "answered" :)